# What is the fastest way to level a hero to level 10?

Tags: hearthstone

I've two heros to level 10, and now I got a daily quest that is specific to two classes that I still have at level 1. Winning with those with a basic deck lacking any of the cards you gain on the way to level 10 looks very unlikely. I've played reasonably successful with my mage, so my opponents now are a bit too strong for a level 1 basic deck.

Levelling with practice games against the regular AI is tediously slow and boring. But playing casual or ranked games seems mostly suicide without it, though it might be an option if the XP gain even when defeated would be higher than in practice. Or should I play against the expert AI?

Which is the fastest way to level up my heros to 10 so that I can properly use them with all the basic cards?

Answer (score 11):

The fastest way to level is hands down by playing games against real opponents. This can be done in either play mode or Arena.

Arena may be best (if you're doing well for gold or don't mind spending the money) because you get to use cards you wouldn't have and the wins and losses still grant you experience. The arena cards you get to use would grant you a stronger deck for that class and would give you (a theoretically) high chance to win than with the basic decks you have. Please note that you will only have the option between 3 classes in arena and may not get the one you need to level (credit: ChrisHateZ)

You can still create custom decks even at low levels. Whatever common cards you may have earned can help in this cause so you can build stronger decks. In play mode, you can gain the experience in either casual or ranked. There is no experience difference gained there, just your ranking.

Also, games that last longer (in the same level) generally give more experience than quick ending games in my experience.

The only reasons to play against the expert AI is to test a deck you are building before putting it out into real play and to complete the quest that requires you to defeat all Expert AI opponents (which will reward you will gold).

Comment: You should also mention that arena makes you pick between 3 random heroes, so you might not get to play with the hero you want to level. Which is risky.

Comment: I found beating down the expert priest using a fast deck was very easy to do.  Yes you get less xp for doing it fast but you can play him a lot of times in short order.

Answer (score 8):

Fastest way to level up your heroes to level 10 is to do the practice matches with each of them. Until you reach level 10 with a hero, beating the AI gives the same amount of experience as beating a player. However, when playing against AI, you don't need to wait for the spinning wheel to find an opponent. Finally, the training AI is usually easier to beat then the real players, unless the opponent is AFK, then it's a matter of waiting 3 minutes.

Starting at level 10, you get less experience from the practice matches, and you should play against real players.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this? Does expert AI yield the same amount of XP?

Comment: It says so in the tutorial

Comment: I just got the random tip message saying you get less after level 10. Wasn't aware it actually said so in the tutorial. I guess I paid too little attention to anything besides the actual games :P

Answer (score 3):

Personally I found it frustrating to play against real people with a partially completed deck (due to lack of even the most basic cards), as Sorean suggests.

I'm far more fond of Master-Guy's suggestion to beat the computer a few times. I found that the **basic AI shaman deck is really really simple to kill** - he will often hex a low cost minion, cast windfury on a freshly spawned minion with no charge or do other silly things like that.

So I've taken to fighting this particular practise session over and over for initial leveling. It's faster and less frustrating that playing against other players at this point. ;)

Answer (score 1):

i just challenge my friends to custom matches. Just play normal until ur friend knows he can kill you and have him quit. As of right now i have no proof that u get more xp by playing more cards during a game but most games are like that so i just assumed that you lvl faster the more you play cards, draw cards, heal, deal dmg, ect.. and then the win from your friend conceding doesn't hurt either. this really only works till ten cuz custom games dont give you much for rewards besides xp. Playing real games gives gold which is what you want if your going to be serious about the game and build reliable decks.

Answer (score 1):

A hero gets XP for wins, playing cards, and killing minions. Maximize that. The fastest way to level characters to 10 is by creating **rushy, low-cost decks** and playing against basic (i.e. PvE, computer) opponents. Don't waste time thinking about your plays, waiting for the opponent to think about theirs, or waiting for the PvP matchmaking system to find someone.

The extra XP from a win is important but if you're playing enough cards and killing enough minions the win (tho helpful) isn't *essential*. Rather than ending matches ASAP and grabbing 30 XP you might want to pass a late-game turn for a chance to play more cards and kill more minions. None of the basic opponents have anything scary for you to worry about. Just build a custom deck of the needed class and fill it with 1-, 2-, and 3-cost minions and spells, leaning heavily towards card draw.

Note that you can't level up more than once from a single match, no matter how many cards you play or minions you kill; from anywhere in level 4, the highest you can advance to is level 5.99. At somewhere around 5 cards left to draw you'll be maxed out in XP and hence can just finish the game.

Personally I've found the basic paladin a good opponent; he summons extra weenies to kill, while the Mage can ping your 1-health minions, Shamans have a lot of 2-health totems to worry about, Rogues have access to a dagger that can kill 1/1s, etc. Does the basic lock run murlocs? That might be good, too, I'll have to check later.

Answer (score 0):

I found each class has a best class to play. I also just played the same AI opponent over and over. Currently working on my druid deck, facing the rogue is super easy and quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually quickly level up on the first levels by starting a ranked game and conceding immediately. It is pretty quick and you get enough experience to skip 3/4 levels in matter of minutes.

Then continuing to fight on the ladder play or casual mode gives the most experience.

The more cards you play the more xp you get. 
So if you are losing or winning on a specific turn, it is always better to play as much cards as possible before concluding the match, to gain those little xp advantages that speed up the process